# Unable to Update Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates

**Error Message:**

`Your device is missing important security and quality fixes.`

[image: Unable to Update Windows 10 message]

My current Windows Version is:

[image: Current Windows 10 Version]

I ran into this problem once before about a year ago or so. After some research, I found that the problem was a Windows update that I needed to uninstall. I uninstalled that update and everything was fine.

I do see 3 updates listed, sadly not the zillion more that Windows keeps downloading. The last update was on September 12th, KB4456655. When I right click on any of the Windows Updates, there is no uninstall option.

[image: My Update History]

I ran the `troubleshooter`, which did nothing useful. There was a batch file that supposed deleted the update folder and whatnot for recreation, which as expected did nothing.

The problem really does seem like there was either a patch that Microsoft wants, which I do not have and a newer download prevents that from installing, or, like before, an update that was installed that should be uninstalled, not that I know which one that is and how to uninstall it.

The problem could be anything.

Thoughts?

**Update**

`sfc /scannow`: No Issues
`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`: No Issues

** Update 2 **

System: Windows 10 Professional x64

As I said in the comments, I finally downloaded the media creation tool, went through the process last night and let the update do its thing. When I got in this morning, I saw the system sort of hung. I saw "installing important updates... Do not turn off your computer," however a ctrl+alt-del showed the system responsive, so I signed out and back in. I went through updating the system again and the exact same problem.

Sadly, Microsoft or whatever deleted my system restore points, so no previous one.

Comment: First try the steps in [r0flm4k3r's answer](//superuser.com/a/1360301/776028), if they don't help, run `SFC /SCANNOW`, if that finds issues but is unable to fix them, run `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`, when it's done, reboot and run `SFC /SCANNOW` again. If none of that helps, download the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and use it to "upgrade" your system *without* erasing files/apps. It'll download the latest version of Windows 10, including (most if not all) updates, and repair your current install.

Comment: The vote to close is rude. I did not reinstall the latest update, but that is harsh. I have seen this problem before, and it happens frequently enough from what I see that there should be a real solution, not sweeping the issue under the rug.

Comment: Did the repair I recommended via the Media Creation Tool work for you?

Comment: @3D1T0R I will try it out tomorrow. I got very busy these last couple of days. Stay tuned.

Comment: @3D1T0R "The language or edition of your PC is not supported by this tool." Windows 10 Enterprise is the top of the line, just not in a good way. I will have to download the ISO and perform an upgrade.

Comment: I've never had that happen. What version (language, edition, 32/64-bit, version & build numbers) are you using!? Then again, I've always used the Media Creation tool to either download an ISO, or put it on a USB Flash Drive, then used that media to install/upgrade.

Comment: Some update such as security update is unavailable to re-install once you installed it on your device. For those update, it is virtal for protect system security and stable. But for some other feature update, we could uninstall after installed. If you want to uninstall security update, we could try to restore system to the previous point.

Comment: @3D1T0R I am using Windows 10 Professional x64 and the media creation tool process did NOT resolve the issue. The process got stuck at the end with "installing important updates". I then logged in (stopped the stuck task), and did updates manually after that and nothing.

Comment: @Joy Microsoft or something deleted all my system restore points, sadly. CCleaner shows them nicely. It makes sense that the media creation tool approach would fail, because it looks like a previous update causes the system to hang or a missing one.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger: I would recommend trying it again, but this time using the Media Creation tool to make an Windows 10 installation USB drive, and when it's finished, and you run the installer, uncheck the box to check for updates while installing.

Comment: @3D1T0R I used the Media Creation tool to make a Windows 10 installation USB drive. Once I created the USB drive, I ran setup on the USB and proceeded.  I unchecked the check for updates. Update checks were done at the tail end, like I said.

Answer (score 0):

You may try cleaning out the /Windows/Software Distribution folder. Most of the Windows Update errors I run into, cleaning out bad files stuck in this directory resolve it for me.

If that does not work, there is a Microsoft Windows Update "fix it" troubleshooter that may help.

[Windows Update troubleshooter page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter)

Comment: A link to the MS FixIt you're referring to would be a good addition to this answer.

Comment: Renaming /Windows/SoftwareDistribution did not work. I had tried that option back on 1/18/2018, which was obviously the last time that I had a problem. This approach did not work then, like now. Great thought. I had simply renamed the folder then to .old.

Comment: Proposed answer did not resolve the issue.

Comment: I went through the media creation tool and that did not work, same problem, sadly.